# TLS Upgradation

Tags: web-services, ups

```
    public bool CheckValidationResult(ServicePoint sp, 
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate cert, WebRequest req, int problem)
    {

        return true;
    }
```

Here , I am in the position to  access  the web service  using Tls 1.2 alone from the web service.

So , after adding the below lines before the  return true in the method. , 
Then ,I can be able to access the  service and also able to get the response.

Is it the correct way to handle these or any other way is there ? ? ?

Please help anyone who has experience on this .

Thanks in Advance.

//Here given protocol version with or operator accepting tls 1.1 ,1.2 and 1.0 along with ssl3

```
        sp.Expect100Continue = true;  
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not the correct way!  Although I am aware that 100's of developers do this (return true for certificate validation), however their communication is no longer secure and is now subject to middleman and replay attacks, which are the most-common SSL attacks known to man.

The truth is you need provide a "comprehensive implementation" for certificate validation, which is based-on several RFCs (search for: X.509 Certificate validation).  At a minimum you need to check the certificates validity (dates), validate subject signature hash using CA's public key and validate CA's CRL revocations (ensure server certficate has not been revoked). However ...

To keep things simple, without degrading TLS's integrity, you could simply check the "problem" (int problem), then return true or false, based on the value of problem.  The OS should set the problem value, based-on internal OS security policy.  Personally, I still would prefer "comprehensive implementation", because OS security policy can be weak, inundated or corrupt (hacked).  Let me know if you need more details on "comprehensive implementation"